# Android driver-to-device map

Tags: android, usb, driver, 3g

In android, is there a file or a database which decides which driver (module) will be loaded for a certain USB device?

**Some background:**

I have a 3g modem which is "supported" by the manufacturer and gets a `/dev/ttyUSBx` file. I have a phone which can be used as a 3g modem (it works in Linux, just have to force usbserial driver).

My problem is that Android loads cdc_acm driver and creates a `/dev/ttyACMx` file. In this case the mobile net capability does not show up in Android menus.

My goal is to find the mechanism which handles the 3g modem but ignores the phone. The standard method: `insmod usbserial vendor=0xVVVV product=0xPPPP` does not work (usbserial module not found). - But clearly there is a mechanism that handles the modem (so it handles usbserial protocol well), but choses to ignore the phone.

Note: modeswitching has nothing to do with it.

Note2: I know this is not strictly a *coding* question but it is certainly not "user level" stuff either, so I think this site has the best audience to answer it.